# MS SQL update Query, gotta be something simple

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I am trying to set every row's CheckColor to *Blue* in the table tblCheckbook (why the hell do people add tbl to the start of every table, I think I know it's a table).

I'm using this query

```
UPDATE    tblCheckbook
SET       CheckColor = Blue
```

However, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express complains Invalid column name 'Blue'.

This has to be a simple fix. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I hope you have a where clause in, too. Otherwise, you'll be updating EVERY record in that table.

Comment: That's the point :) I was trying double quotes but it was giving the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE    tblCheckbook
SET       CheckColor = 'Blue'
```

Answer (score 7):

use 'Blue' not Blue

Answer (score 4):

Try adding quote around Blue

```
UPDATE tblCheckbook SET CheckColor = 'Blue'
```